# Best way to overwrite (replace) a redis list in python

Tags: python, redis

I need to store a python list (order is important) in a Redis. Currently, I use the following code to do this:

```py
import redis
redis_conn = redis.StrictRedis(host='localhost', port=6379)

r = redis_conn.rpush('key', *a_python_list)
```

But I need to overwrite (replace) the current key (current stored list values) with new values each time I run the python script instead of appending the list to the previous values for that key. I know that I can delete the whole old list by removing the stored key and `rpush` the list again using the following code:

```py
import redis
redis_conn = redis.StrictRedis(host='localhost', port=6379)

if redis_conn.exists('key'):
    redis_conn.delete(redis_key)

r = redis_conn.rpush('key', *a_python_list)
```

I want to know that if there is a built-in redis command (or a better way) to replace the whole of existing list with the new list for a key instead of appending it?

Comment: so you want to overwrite the whole list each time?

Comment: @aws_apprentice yes.

Comment: There isn't a LIST command for this, but you could convert the list to a JSON string, then use SET, which would always reset the value.

Answer (score 4):

Using a [redis pipeline](https://redis-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/connections.html?highlight=pipeline#redis.Redis.pipeline) wraps in a transaction:

```py
import redis
r = redis.Redis()

with r.pipeline() as pipe:
    pipe.delete('foo')
    pipe.rpush('foo', *[1, 2, 3, 4])
    pipe.execute()
```

Answer (score -3):

You can do this:

```
example = {
    "id": 1,
    "description": "test"
}

json_example = json.dumps(example)

redis.set('example-key', json_example)
```

and then:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> get example-key
"{\"id\": 1, \"description\": \"test\"}"
```